# Update DataTable on change

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a on change event attached to my dataTable which seems to update the dataTable correctly but in the front end, the dropdown value is always set to the first option no matter what option is selected. What am I doing wrong? On change seems to work fine for input. For textarea as well (comments box), the value does not seem to hold.

If I remove on change function, then the front end works just fine (The dropdown option is selected correctly). However, the datatable is not updated. So I need the on change function. As requested, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyzpv42o/3/

DataTable definition

```
    $('#firstDoseEligibility_table').DataTable({
      "pageLength": 5,
      data: result,
      "columnDefs":[{"targets":[12], render : function(data, type, row, meta) {
        var a = result.indexOf(row);
        var $select = $("<select class = 'browser-default' id='eligible_1st_"+a+"'><option value='Yes'>Yes</option><option value ='Y'>Y</option><option value ='No'>No</option</select>");        
        $("#eligible_1st_"+a).val("");        
        return $select.prop("outerHTML")        
      }},                      
                    {"targets":[13], render : function(ditem){return "<input type='date' value = '" + ditem +"'/>";}},
                    {"targets":[14], render : function(ditem){return "<textarea rows='4' cols='80' value = '" + ditem +"'/>";}}
                   ],
      columns: [
        {"title":"FQM Mine Numer"},
        {"title":"First Name"},
        {"title":"Last Name"},
        {"title":"Company"},
        {"title":"Age"},
        {"title":"Underlying conditions"},
        {"title":"Allergies towards previous vaccines"},
        {"title":"Active COVID-19 infection"},
        {"title":"Date of previous COVID-19 infection"},
        {"title":"No. of Weeks from COVID Diagnosis"},
        {"title":"Pregnant"},
        {"title":"Tier"},
        {"title":"Eligible", "className": ""},
        {"title":"Date to be Vaccinated(1st Dose)", "className": ""},
        {"title":"Comments", "className": ""}
      ]
    });
```

On change function

```
  $( '#firstDoseEligibility_table' ).on( 'change', 'input,select,textarea', function () {
    //Get the cell of the input
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    //update the input value
    console.log($(this).val());
    $('#firstDoseEligibility_table').DataTable().cell($(cell)).data($(this).val());
    console.log($('#firstDoseEligibility_table').DataTable().rows().data().toArray());
  } );
```

Comment: Try putting a console log of the selected value after you change the datatable data, it's doing a refresh when you update it's data. I'm not sure what the issue may be at this point.

Comment: console.log($(this).val()) output remains the same before and after updating the datatable

Comment: If you can reproduce in a fiddle I'll gladly take a look

Comment: yes, here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/cyzpv42o/3/

Comment: What's the use of this line? If you remove it it works `$('#firstDoseEligibility_table').DataTable().cell($(cell)).data($(this).val());`

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy, this is to update the datatable with the new value. Otherwise the new value is lost